# Join multiple files

Tags: text-processing, join

I have multiple .txt files and would like to merge them together base on their first column (numeric), and fill in "NULL" if there's any missing data.

File_1:

```
1 a
2 b
3 c
```

File_2:

```
3 c
4 d
5 e
```

File_3:

```
4 d
5 e
6 f
```

Expected_Output:

```
1 a NULL NULL
2 b NULL NULL
3 c c NULL
4 NULL d d
5 NULL e e
6 NULL NULL f
```

`join -t $'\t' -a 1 -a 2 -1 1 -2 1 -e NULL -o 0,1.2,2.2 file_1 file_2 | join -t $'\t' -a 1 -a 2 -1 1 -2 1 -e NULL - file_3 > expected_output` This command give me correct output of column 1, 2 and 3 ;however, "NULL" is missing in column 4, any idea how to fix it? 
Also is there a better way to merge multiple files instead writing a super long pipe command?

Comment: There's another answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/13963634 which is suitable for any number of files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there. Using your command, we get:

```
$ join -t $'\t' -a 1 -a 2 -1 1 -2 1 -e NULL -o 0,1.2,2.2 file_1 file_2 | join -t $'\t' -a 1 -a 2 -1 1 -2 1 -e NULL - file_3
1       a       NULL
2       b       NULL
3       c       c
4       NULL    d       d
5       NULL    e       e
6       f
```

Lines just don't have the same number of columns because we are not setting a format for the right-hand `join` in the pipeline.

If we add it as `-o 0,1.2,1.3,2.2` (the join field + the second and third columns from the first join + the second column of `file_3`):

```
$ join -t $'\t' -a 1 -a 2 -1 1 -2 1 -e NULL -o 0,1.2,2.2 file_1 file_2 | join -t $'\t' -a 1 -a 2 -1 1 -2 1 -e NULL -o 0,1.2,1.3,2.2 - file_3
1       a       NULL    NULL
2       b       NULL    NULL
3       c       c       NULL
4       NULL    d       d
5       NULL    e       e
6       NULL    NULL    f
```

Finally, if we can assume the GNU implementation of `join`, we can let it do the job of inferring the right format and use `-o auto` instead of `-o 0,1.2,2.2` and `-o 0,1.2,1.3,2.2`, provided that, for each file, all lines have at most the same number of fields as the first one. [Quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/General-options-in-join.html#General-options-in-join) `info join`:

> `-o auto`
>   If the keyword `auto` is specified, infer the output format from the first line in each file.  This is the same as the default output format but also ensures the same number of fields are output for each line. Missing fields are replaced with the `-e` option and extra fields are discarded.

Comment: "-o auto" gives me the following error: " join: malformed -o option field".

Comment: @user368151 My fault, I forgot to point it out. `auto` is an extension to POSIX. Answer amended. Users with access to GNU Coreutils will have it, others probably won't.

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on things learned from https://stackoverflow.com/a/13963634 and [fra-san](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/536798/364705)

This will work for any number of files.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
tempdir=$(mktemp --directory)
trap "rm -r $tempdir" EXIT SIGTERM

for infile in "$@"; do
  sort "$infile" > "${tempdir}/${infile}.sorted"
  if [ -e "${tempdir}/final.results" ]
  then
    join -a1 -a2 -e "NULL" -o auto \
      "${tempdir}/final.results" "${tempdir}/${infile}.sorted" \
      > "${tempdir}/res"
    mv "${tempdir}/res" "${tempdir}/final.results"
  else
    cp "${tempdir}/${infile}.sorted" "${tempdir}/final.results"
  fi
done
cat "${tempdir}/final.results"
```

Result:

```
$ . join_multiple_files.sh file* | column -t
1  a     NULL  NULL
2  b     NULL  NULL
3  c     c     NULL
4  NULL  d     d
5  NULL  e     e
6  NULL  NULL  f
```